# Determine File relative to other file in Java

Tags: java, file, path

I am parsing a html file with Java and identify some images in it, for example "../../../image.png", "./img/image.png" or "/image.png".
I have the path of the html file (as File Object) and need to determine the location of the images.
What would be the easiest wasy to do so? Is there any Library?

Comment: Can you clarify that? Do you want the exact location of these image files? If this is the case, then use [`imageFile.getgetCanonicalPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Path.relativize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)), `resolve`, `resolveSibling` and `normalize`.

- Path is the "successor" of File, for dealing with different "file systems" like a zip folder. You can use File.toPath()`
- `Paths.get("...")` creates a Path, and
- `Files` provides functions for doing things like copying.

Something like:

```
Path htmlPath = Paths.get("C:/test/index.html");
Path path = htmlPath.resolveSibling("../img/favicon.ico");
```